# Readonly Input field will not fire OnKeyPress in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, readonly, onkeypress

I am implementing a special behaviour for the Enter key. The problem is my ASP.net library generates a readonly field; and when users tab into this field (tabbing into it is meaningful; so I want that behaviour) and press Enter to submit the form, it won't submit because it's a readonly field.

I wrote a workaround that hooks up your ordinary onkeypress=checkEnter, but IE6 will still not fire this event; Firefox will.

Whan can I do to detect an Enter on an IE6 readonly field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason IE6 won't detect pressing `ENTER` on the keypress event. It does however detect `ENTER` on the keydown and keyup events. Try the `onkeyup=checkEnter` instead of onkeypress. I just tested that and it works.

**EDIT:** According to this [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) article, `Keypress` fires when actual characters are being inserted. `keyup`/`keydown` fire on all keys. However, this behavior is different in FF and IE8.